# Вычислительная сложность алгоритма c#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Действия Action1 и Action2 выполняются за константное время. 
Определить вычислительную сложность алгоритма при A=1.5, A=1 и A=2.

Правильно ли я понимаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е при A=1.5, A=1 и A=2 сложность линейная, а при А >=3 цикл бесконечный?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запишем в виде, подходящем для [Master Theorem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

```
 T(n) = a * (n / b) + n^c
 T(n) = 2 * T(A/3 * n) + n
 т.е.  a = 2, b = 3/A,  c = 1
```

и оценим log<sub>b</sub>(a) для значений A =1, 1.5, 2

```
 A      b     logb(2)
 1      3      < 1
 3/2    2       1
 2      3/2     >1
```

В первом случае срабатывает третий вариант, и сложность `Theta(n)`

Во втором случае срабатывает второй вариант, и сложность `Theta(n * log(n))`

В третьем случае срабатывает первый вариант, и сложность
Theta(n^log<sub>3/2</sub>(2))`~ Theta(n^1.7)`

Comment: @all zoom Поправил числа в последнем случае